# USB device recognised but not usable

Tags: debian, usb

I'm trying to use a USB flash drive that was working perfectly until some time ago, after which I have made no changes to the system that can affect this.

When I plug in my USB device and run `$ lsblk && lsusb`
this is the output I received.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    28G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0 895.2G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b90 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can note the `SanDisk Corp. Ultra at Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5581` in the above output.

I do not understand why it was not mounted automatically and why I am unable to mount it. Please help me out with how to mount the device. Thanks in advance :)

Edit: This is happening with all USB devices, I did try connecting an external hard disk. The same thing happened.

Edit: I'm extremely sorry that I did not provide the basic information.
I'm Using Debian 10 (Buster) with a the latest kernel i.e. `5.8.0-rc1-00001-gc1966b82e604`

When I run `sudo journalctl -f`

```
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5581, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: Product: Ultra
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001161117117402
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu mtp-probe[2747]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu mtp-probe[2747]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu mtp-probe[2750]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu.pes.edu mtp-probe[2750]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Jun 20 19:24:18 pesu.pes.edu kernel: usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

When I run
`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` this is the output i get.

```
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu kernel: [ 1110.256157] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu kernel: [ 1110.256162] usb 1-3: Product: Ultra
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu kernel: [ 1110.256166] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu kernel: [ 1110.256170] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001161117117402
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Jun 20 19:24:12 pesu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Jun 20 19:24:18 pesu kernel: [ 1116.267124] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

Comment: What's your OS and version? Can you `sudo journalctl  -f` while you plug things in? Or must you `tail -f /var/log/syslog` ? Or read the most recently changed log file as shown by `ls -lrt /var/log`?

Comment: Hey @waltinator ,Thank you for responding.  Extremely sorry for not providing that information earlier. I've made an edit :)

Comment: Please show the output of `lsblk` to see whether the USB device got mapped to a block (disk type) device. You can leave out the details about your main hard disk.

Comment: Hi @Ned64 I've already shown the output of ```lsblk``` in the first piece of code, the command was ```$ lsblk && lsusb```

Comment: Oops, sorry. There is no entry.  Then no mount command will help.  You would expect `usbcore` to register a `usb-storage` device which hasn't happened. Have you made a system update without rebooting?  Or, have you blacklisted any usb (kernel) modules?  Or, have you changed udev rules by hand?  Also: please check `systemctl status systemd-udevd`.

Comment: @Ned64 First of all, I haven't made a system update without reeboting, I always do ```make && sudo make -j3 install``` and then ```sudo init 6```. I do not know if this is relevant, but whenever I run ```make -j3 install``` without ```make``` before it, I always get an error saying ```modules.builtin``` is missing. Thus ```su -c "make modules_install install" ``` also throws an error. I am really not sure if it is relevant, but I didn't want to leave anything out.

Comment: OK, you have messed^H^H^H^H^H^Hcompiled your own kernel. No problem if you have the right modules. Please test `modprobe usbcore` and `modprobe usb_storage` (all as root) I guess these may simply be missing. `lsmod | grep usb | sort` will also tell you which modules are currently loaded (run after those two commands).

Comment: ```$ sudo modprobe usbcore
$ sudo modprobe usb_storage
modprobe: FATAL: Module usb_storage not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-rc1-00001-gc1966b82e604```

Comment: Thank you @Ned64, please post that as answer in order for me to accept it. Thank you :)

Comment: Done. Feel free to vote up and accept (two steps). Ready to solve your issue if you add details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel needs the modules `usbcore` and `usb_storage` to recognise USB devices as USB storage devices.  This includes USB thumb drives.

According to your output in the comments above, quoting here:

```
$ sudo modprobe usb_storage
modprobe: FATAL: Module usb_storage not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-rc1-00001-gc1966b82e604
```

The kernel does not have the `usb_storage` module/code available.

Solution 1:
Compile your kernel with `usb_storage` included (Y not M).

Solution 2: Fix your issues compiling your kernel modules (need more info to solve that issue, feel free to add kernel module compilation/installation errors by editing your question, or (perhaps better) open a new question since it is a different problem).

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but this is what my .config file says. Can you please tell me exactly what i need to modify over here? I seem to be messing it up. Thanks```# # NOTE: USB_STORAGE depends on SCSI but BLK_DEV_SD may # # # also be needed; see USB_STORAGE Help for more info # CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=m # CONFIG_USB_STORAGE_DEBUG is not set``` because ```make``` seems to have issues when I change that ```m``` to a ```y```

Comment: What happens if you do what it says: Change `BLK_DEV_SD` and `SCSI` to `Y` (not `M`)?

Comment: I did not see ```INSTALL drivers/usb/usb_storage.o``` while executing ```su -c "make modules_install install"``` hence, same problem again. I did change the following lines /to in the .config file ```BLK_DEV_SD=y``` and ```CONFIG_SCSI=y```

Comment: If you say "Y" not "M" you would not see NAME.o installation because code is not compiled into a module file but included into the kernel itself. The code will still be in the kernel (unless an error occurs) and things should work. I have suggested the "Y not M" approach because you seem to have module installation problems (see your previous comment above). If these are gone "M" should work, too.

Comment: I changed them to Y as suggested, and rebuilt it. It still doesn't work

Comment: Any new error/kernel messages, any change? We need something to work with.

Comment: Sorry, but ```dmesg``` was empty, I mean there was nothing regarding this.

Comment: OK, let's revert to "M" again (though "Y" ought to work imho) and fix your module installation problem. Perhaps you want to open a new question just for this? It is more about kernel compilation than how USB devices are recognised as disks.

Comment: Yes I guess you're right. I will open a new question.